# instagram user checker

Tags: python, instagram

```
print(os.linesep)
tag=input("your username here : ")



instagram ='https://www.instagram.com/'
x=requests.get(instagram+tag)
if x.status_code == 200:
  print("Instagram found: "+tag)
else:
    print("not found")
```

how to make the instagram checker open a text file and check every single user if it is available or not ?

Comment: Can you please edit the post to describe the expected output from the code and what you are currently getting?

Comment: alright i will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the usernames you wish to check into a text file, then read that text file using `for loop` to go through each name-checking if it is available.

For Example

```py
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     for name in lines:
        checkInstagram(name)
```

I would recommend making the `checkInstagram` Function as it will make the code look a lot neater.

**Edit**

I have added a little bit of code that will open the Instagram page this is done using the webbrowser module `import webbrowser`

Code:
`webbrowser.open(f'{instagram+tag}', new=2)`

Use this if you want but I hope I was helpful

Comment: thank u but unfortunately it didn't work or i didn't get it , please if u don't mind giving me ur name at any social media program so i can contact u

Comment: @Band Up message me on Twitter my username is MattCodes03

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm pretty sure you'll run into some rate limits real soon and you would probably be violating Instagram's terms of use, I'd hack up something like this:

```
usernames_to_check = ['bandup1', 'bandup2', 'bandup3']
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for username in usernames_to_check:
        x = requests.get(instagram + tag)
        if x.status_code == 200:
            outfile.write(f"Instagram found: {tag}\n")
        else:
            outfile.write(f"not found: {tag}\n")
```

Comment: thank u but unfortunately it didn't work or i didn't get it , please if u don't mind giving me ur name at any social media program so i can contact u